# How could a rocky planet be tilted on its side?

Tags: planets, habitability, axial-tilt

I want to experiment with a rocky planet that's tilted on its side like Uranus. But first I of course need some way for this to happen without destroying any chances of the planet being habitable. Would a massive collision be the only solution?

Comment: What makes you think a massive collision would destroy any chances of the planet being habitable? It happened on Earth, and here we are...

Comment: The *"massive collision"* (or something else) would have happened A Very Long Time Ago, long before the emergence of life. And exceptional inclinations are not as rare as you see to think: for example, poor [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus) rotates (veeeery slowly) *backwards*, as if *something* had knocked it off almost 180°. In the case of Venus, astronomers believe that its retrograde rotation came about *"because of chaotic spin changes caused by planetary perturbations and tidal effects on its dense atmosphere over the course of billions of years"* (Wikipedia).

Comment: Why is it that the axis of rotation is usually close to the axis of orbit?

Comment: @Daron this is because planets are forming from a protoplanetary disk. There is a lot of rotational momentum in the plane of this disk, and not so much perpendicular to this disk. Fluctuations in in-the-plane momentum end up in planets' rotational momentum, and perpendicular, "normal" momentum ends up in planets' orbital and axial tilt.

Comment: What do you gain by changing the axis of rotation?

Comment: By any reasonable standard, Earth is pretty well tilted on its side.  Most planets are, Mercury & Jupiter being the exceptions (if you consider Venus as being tilted more than 180 degrees): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt#Solar_System_bodies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to wait hundreds of millions of years tidal forces can do it. Over the last 500 million years, the moon has changed the earth's rotation 10% (from a 22 hour day to a 24 hour day).

Were a new, massive, moon to appear, on a perfectly perpendicular orbit to its current rotation, you could tilt Uranus 10 to 15 degrees in only a billion years or so.

Referring to calculations done on https://what-if.xkcd.com/26/ Changing the rotational velocity of the earth by enough to shorten the day by 0.8milliseconds, or by 0.00011574% (ie enough to remove leap seconds) would require a dinosaur-killing asteroid every 48 hours. An impact capable of changing the tilt more than a few hundredths of a degree is going to be a planet killer.

Comment: Interesting.How big would the moon have to be compared to the planet? Would the moon orbit around the dipped equator?